# Install IIS 8.0 or later on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, iis, iis-8

Are there any methos to install IIS 8.0 on windows 7?
As I searched, IIS is available with OS only and not as a independent package to install. Only Express version of IIS is available to download and install.

But if there is any method to install newer version of IIS on windows 7, I will be thankful if you share it.

Comment: Only IIS 7.5 can be installed on Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2.  If you want a later version use a newer version of Windows.  If you want IIS 8 then install Windows 8.0

Comment: @Ramhound Windows 7 comes with IIS 6.0. How can I install IIS7.5 on windows 7?

Comment: According to my research it comes with IIS 7.5 you install the same way as any other version of IIS.   IIS 6.5 according to my research doesn’t exist.  IIS 6 came with Windows XP and IIS 7 came with Windows Vista